# messed up my date formatting with java

Tags: java, mysql

So i'm using a code to parse strings to date,but did it the wrong way so it got recorded on my mysql database in a wrong format.

like the following :
**the code :**

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse("2017-10-20").getTime()));
```

**output :**

```
0026-04-09
```

I wonder how to reverse that to get 2017-10-20 out of the string 0026-04-09

Comment: Why don't you just switch around the date format to be `yyyy-MM-dd` instead?

Comment: tried it on the date 0026-04-09 , it gives 0026-04-09 also , the problem is i'm trying to reverse what i recorded for the other dates too

Comment: So you have `0026-04-09` in your database now and want to correct it back to `2017-10-20`? Is that stored as a string or as a date? I’m not sure there is a bulletproof way, but with some more information we can better tell.

Comment: true, it's now stored as 0026-04-09 and as a date not a string , if i only could know how it got 2017-10-20 to 0026-04-09 on a dd-MM-yyyy date parsing .. it would be solved

Comment: I think what you have is the 2017th day of October year 20 AD. 2017 days is approximately 5 and a half years, so this would be in the first half of year 26 AD. Are all your dates in, say, the range from 2010 to 2020? Problem could be if you could have 1986-11-20, because that would have been 0026-04-09 too and you could not tell.

Comment: actually all of them are in the range  2010-2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest and least complicated way is to do the wrong calculations again for all dates that could possibly be in your database. Then you know what they yield and you will be able to go back to what the date should have been. Use a map to map from the wrong date (as `Date` or as `String`) to the the one it should have been.

I am using

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

I am also using `LocalDate` and `Month` from `java.time` — these require Java 8. If you are using Java 7, you can use `java.util.Calendar` instead. Code example — to be tailored to your needs:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Map<Date, Date> corrections = new HashMap<>(5500); // capacity for 11 years
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 31);
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.of(2010, Month.JANUARY, 1);

    do {
        Date correctDate = Date.valueOf(currentDate);
        String correctString = correctDate.toString();
        Date wrongDate = new Date(dateFormat.parse(correctString).getTime());

        if (corrections.containsKey(wrongDate)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate wrong date " + wrongDate);
        }

        corrections.put(wrongDate, correctDate);

        currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
    } while (! currentDate.isAfter(endDate));
```

With the chosen dates, running the above code does *not* cause the `Duplicate wrong date` line to be printed, so within the interval from 2010 to 2020 we can convert back unambiguously. A relief, isn’t it?

Now you have built the map, the lookup is easy, for example:

```
    Date wrongDate = new Date(dateFormat.parse("2017-10-20").getTime()); // 0026-04-09
    Date correctDate = corrections.get(wrongDate);
    if (correctDate == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find correction for " + wrongDate);
    } else {
        System.out.println(correctDate);
    }
```

This prints the desired:

```
2017-10-20
```

You will want to make sure you don’t get a `null` before you put the value back into your database.

If you have a modern JDBC driver, you should also be able to avoid `java.sql.Date` in the above code and use the modern `LocalDate` and friends all the way through.